# Under app name xcode current branch always loading

Tags: xcode, gitlab, git-branch

[image: loading branch]

hey guys i want to ask, my current branch keep loading and not stopping. and it drain my mac battery faster. i don't have any clue what happens, is there something wrong with my remote branch?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> Xcode - Preferences - Source Control - General

Uncheck and then check the "Enable Source Control".